# How to correlate transaction receipts to Financial Report which can download in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to correlate receipts from the payment object to information received in either the financial reports, sales reports or bank statements?

I record all purchase info in my database whatever verifying is success. When I check the financial reports in iTunes connect, I found I have received 3 more payment. My problem is how can I know who need compensated?

Apple's Receipt include quantity, product_id, transaction_id, purchase_date, original_transaction_id, original_purchase_date, app_item_id, version_external_identifier, bid, bvrs.

Financial report include Start Date, End Date, UPC, ISRC/ISBN, Vendor Identifier, Quantity, Partner Share, Extended Partner Share, Partner Share Currency, Sales or Return, Apple Identifier, Artist/Show/Developer/Author, Title   Label/Studio/Network/Developer/Publisher, Grid, Product Type Identifier, ISAN/Other Identifier, Country Of Sale, Pre-order Flag, Promo Code, Customer Price, Customer Currency.

Answer (score 1):

I have a (free) tool to do this for Google & Amazon app stores, and am currently adding support for Apple (30 June 2014). It allows you to apportion sales by app or individual in-app purchases, regardless of currency. This is currently quite difficult for Amazon and Apple especially.  You can find the code here: https://github.com/eggheadgames/app_earnings. You'll need Ruby installed to run it.

*Update Nov 2019*: For Apple I now use a paid service, `appfigures.com`, which provides purchase info by in-app purchase and app, verified back to actual payment deposits. I still use my own tool for Google & Amazon (as AppFigures only reconciles for Apple). I haven't kept the above repo up-to-date with vendor file format adjustments I've made, but if you comment below, or in the repro, it won't take much nudging.