# Correlate an In-app purchase with the Financial report in IOS

Tags: ios, in-app

I am working with the Inapp purchases in my current app. After successfull purchase i save the "receipt" of the product on my server. I am aware about the "Financial Reports" provided on iTunes Connect at monthly intervals. Now my question is what should i have to do to validate a particular transaction with the Financial report provided by apple. I see some sample Financial reports but couldn't find any such parameter which give the transaction Id or any other unique field.

Also, if there is any way of attaching some payload during the Payment request and get that payload back in the receipt and the Financial report?. This might solve the problem from me.

[Correlate an Inapp transaction with the Financial report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862347/correlate-an-inapp-transaction-with-the-financial-report)

@Hotwheels - did you find any way to do it ? i have similar requirement

Comment: Hey Dharmesh, welcome to StackOverflow! In case you want to ask further questions on another question posted by someone else, please do write a comment on their question instead of opening your own with no additional information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correlate transaction receipts to Financial Report which can download in iTunes Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693214/how-to-correlate-transaction-receipts-to-financial-report-which-can-download-in)

Comment: @peter it was not allowed me to add comments so i opened new thread. Yes it same question but its old thread so i am looking for some way to handling it.